# does the series $ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\left(\frac{n!\cdot \left(-e\right)^n}{n^n}\right) $ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have tried to use the ratio test, but it comes out as one.
I have tried to prove that $ \left| \left(\frac{n!\cdot \left(-e\right)^n}{n^n}\right) \right| $ is a monotonically decreasing function and to apply Dirichlet's theorem about the series of a product but to no avail.

Does it converge? How and why?

Comment: Recall that $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} (n/e)^n$ (from Stirling's approximation).  That suggests that the summands here are asymptotic to $(-1)^n \sqrt{2\pi n}$; i.e., they don't go to zero, and so the sum can't converge.  If $(-e)^n$ were replaced with $x^n$ for any $|x| < e$, you would have absolute convergence.

Comment: so the domain of convergence of the power series $ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\left(\frac{n!\cdot \left(x\right)^n}{n^n}\right) $ is $\left( -e,e \right)$ and not $\left[ -e,e \right)$ ?

Comment: Right.  You got down to the $\pm e$ range with the ratio test.  To show that it doesn’t converge at the endpoints, it’s enough to show the terms don’t go to zero.  I believe looking at the logarithm will help you there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Stirling's approximation as $n\to\infty$
$$
\frac{n!(-1)^ne^n}{n^n}\sim(-1)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}.
$$
Thus, by comparing to the convergence of
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\sqrt n
$$
we conclude the series diverges.

Comment: Is there another way other than comparing the limits of 2 functions? A way that doesn't require Stirling's approximation ?

Comment: @Ak2399 It's not comparing limits between 2 functions; it's asymptotic equivalence. You can  frame it as using the divergence test+Stirling's.

Comment: Suppose we don't know about this approximation, how would we have solved it differently?